# Converting std::string::length to int

Tags: c++

string::length has the return type of size_t, but it seems to able to be put into an int without any casting or anything. Why can I assign a size_t to an int in this case?

```
int main() {
     string line;
     getline(cin, line);
     cout << line << endl;
     int i = line.size();
     int j = line.length();
     cout << i << " " << j << endl;
}
```

Comment: Because it's small enough?

Comment: A good compiler should warn here, especially if the size type is larger than int.

Comment: Remember, an `int` implies the value can go negative.  I have yet to see negative string lengths.  Better to use `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `size_t` values are being narrowed. In c++11, you could make this fail with an error by doing:

```
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string line;
    int i{line.size()};
    int j{line.length()};
}
```

The errors produced look like:

```
gh.cc:5:11: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
    int i{line.size()};
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
gh.cc:5:11: note: override this message by inserting an explicit cast
    int i{line.size()};
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
          static_cast<int>( )
gh.cc:6:11: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
    int j{line.length()};
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
gh.cc:6:11: note: override this message by inserting an explicit cast
    int j{line.length()};
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
          static_cast<int>( )
```

Comment: Why is there no error for what was in my original post? They're essentially the same thing.

Comment: I don't get it. Why would  you write code that you *know* it won't compile?

Comment: I'm just curious why one works and the other doesn't

Comment: @Math2: Let's look at forms 1 and 2 on this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization Note that form 2 does not allow narrowing.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Seems to be a lot more rules in C++ than there is in Java

Comment: @Math2: Oh absolutely!

Answer (score 0):

size_t is a 32 bit integer.
Go to your compiler directory and open the **stdio.h** file.

There is a declaration, something like this:

```
typedef unsigned int size_t;
```

Comment: This is an implementation detail.